# Where can I locate the 'stdout' and 'stderr' log files on Mesos Slave machines?

Tags: mesos, mesos-chronos

I am trying to access the *echo* and *print* logs of my cron tasks in the Mesos Slave machines. I can see the *stdout* and *stderr* logs from the GUI but can't seem to locate them on the machine. So far I tried exploring the location `/var/logs/mesos`. Where are these log files located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after going through a lot of documentation, I finally got my head around this. Posting my observations for someone who might have a similar question. 

[Documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/sandbox/#where-is-the-sandbox)

In each Mesos slave machine the logs (stdout and stderr) can be found in $MESOS_HOME/slaves/[agent-id]/frameworks/[framework-id]/executors/[executor-id]/runs

Also, the GUI shows the complete path on the top when you go to a task > sandbox